# Include Schema validation (.xsd) in Schematron validation (.sch) [not the other way around]

Tags: xml, xsd, schematron, oxygenxml

Since it is easier and less verbose to enforce data structure in an XSD file than it is in a Schematron and since we already have working XSD files to validate single entities, I would like to include these as a first validation phase in my Schematron.

I found tutorials describing the other way around (embedded Schematron rules in XSD).

I found the element `<sch:include href="my.xsd">` but when I validate (with oXygen) it does not seem to make a difference.

It seems I am missing something very obvious as this should be supported without problems or shouldn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there is as far as I know, no concept to include XSD in Schematron. But as you can embed XSLT in Schematron and XSLT schema-aware is able to validate your input data, you can use xsl:import-schema:

```
<sch:schema xmlns:sch="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron" queryBinding="xslt2" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:sqf="http://www.schematron-quickfix.com/validator/process">

    <xsl:import-schema schema-location="path/to/my.xsd"/>

    <!-- [your schematron rules] -->
</sch:schema>
```

In oXygen you need to activate schema-aware for Schematron validations:

Preferences -> XML -> XML-Parser -> Schematron -> Use Saxon EE (schema-aware) for xslt2/xslt3 query language binding.

Comment: Thank you, the only thing that should be mentioned is that this is a premium feature, that only the licensed EE Version of the Saxonica libs provide. oXygen can do it ('cause it's a paid product) but XMLbuddyValidator cannot, as it uses the HE version of the saxon libs.